# Unable to write data into a file

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am trying to write data on to a file in android, but I am unable to do so. Please check my code and guide me for the same.

```
public static final File SCANNED = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/scanned.txt");
private void WriteIntoScannedFile(String tmp) { 


        try{
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(Constants.SCANNED,true);
        LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(Constants.pincode_records));

        //writer.append("App has been activated successfully");
        writer.append(tmp);
writer.append(#);
        writer.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Log cat

```
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/scanned.txt (Is a directory)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:58)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.ecomm.android.ScanShipments.WriteIntoScannedFile(ScanShipments.java:334)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.ecomm.android.ScanShipments.MatchedShipment(ScanShipments.java:238)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.ecomm.android.ScanShipments.AddRecord(ScanShipments.java:208)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.ecomm.android.ScanShipments.access$5(ScanShipments.java:202)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.ecomm.android.ScanShipments$2.onKey(ScanShipments.java:110)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3850)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:386)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1746)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1130)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1722)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2627)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2030)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-01 12:40:24.260: W/System.err(2300):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 12:40:24.260: I/System.out(2300): returning from verified
04-01 12:40:24.310: W/KeyCharacterMap(2300): No keyboard for id 0
04-01 12:40:24.310: W/KeyCharacterMap(2300): Using default keymap
04-01 12:41:13.800: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2300): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

**Please tell me how to write the data inside the android app ie in a file that is inside the app**

Comment: I think scanned.txt file is not present on SD card path you mentioned. Before writing anything in file create file first and then perform write operation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/scanned.txt (Is a directory)` because you have not that file in sdcard but you are tring to write that file.

you have to do this:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"scanned.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
```

you have to add this permission in androidmanifest file;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: but you have't file in sdcard... that is your problem.. i add permission for your refrance..

Answer (score 0):

Please create file first before writing.

```
File SCANNED  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "scanned.txt");
SCANNED.createNewFile();
```

and give write permission in android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```